# Parameter to notebook - widget not defined error

Tags: databricks

I have passed a parameter from JobScheduling to Databricks Notebook and tried capturing it inside the python Notebook using dbutils.widgets.get ().

When I run the scheduled job, I get the error "No Input Widget defined", thrown by the library module ""InputWidgetNotDefined"

May I know the reason, thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have already tried. Refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Tom, myJob Schedule had Key-value  as "someParameter"  "its value". And, inside the notebook, it was intended to be caught as  dbutils.widget.get ("someParamter").  However, this pattern of passing and receiving parameter didn't work, it threw an error "No Input Widget defined", thank you

Comment: How you put the parameter in job Schedule?

Comment: @TomM you are right that question should be asked in a proper way but sometimes it is not possible. People who are concerned with the specific environment can understand it easily and too much explanation is not required all the time.

Answer (score 2):

To use widgets, you fist need to create them in the notebook.

For example, to create a text widget, run:

```
dbutils.widgets.text('date', '2021-01-11')
```

After the widget has been created once on a given cluster, it can be used to supply parameters to the notebook on subsequent job runs.